# How to migrate a nodejs application(developed on localhost) to a linux server where nodejs is already installed?

Tags: node.js, linux, server, localhost, migrate

I have a node application developed on my xampp/lampp/localhost which i want to shift to a live server which is a linux server, I have already setting up node there but don't know how to make my application run on the web url. 
In the localhost we run the application with node command:

> > node server.js

and its run the application on a specific port which we setup on the code.
But how to make it run on the live server. DO i have to setup any cron job to run the node command always?

I am new on this thing and didn't find any best answer over the web. Please guide me through this who already did this before

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some kind of "application server". Like, say, [uwsgi](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download.html) or [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). And then you'll need to setup one of them (both have fully described documentation) to run your application.
And you can run [NginX](http://nginx.org/) in front of one of them, to serve static files.

Also, [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) can be build as either NginX or Apache module (but requires some compilation).

Answer (score 0):

You can access your live server using putty SSH Terminal and run a command there such as

```
node server.js
```

Comment: I have run the command on putty and its run successfully but i dont know where to see the preview. Where it should appear? on the http://example.org:port?

Comment: if you are on a linux server putty terminal...try `ls` to preview files and folders

Comment: if you want to see your files on a GUI, you can try using SFTP..try it using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)...

Comment: no i didn't mean to view files, that i know.But where to see the web application preview

Comment: do you have a domain?...if you have a domain, point your domain DNS to your live server..

Comment: yes i have a domain and its already pointing towards the live server

Comment: @HarishKumar, Did you find any solution? Please let me know.